# Does make_my_diffs_pretty! slow down my test suite only when there are errors?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I discovered that I can add `make_my_diffs_pretty!` on my tests, and it's super nice to have a decent diff for complex structures.

I was reading that it's slower than the normal diffs, but is it slower only when outputting the result of a non-passing test? (And so, it's slower only when the tests are not passing?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It slows down certain tests that are passing **or** failing. But the impact of this performance loss is totally dependant on *your* specific test suite - so you'll need to benchmark it on your own application in order to measure the difference!

[Here is the source code](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/1146f43e56e8b6decd2c8ddd88d9fd9b9d3deedb/lib/minitest/test.rb#L44-L48) for `make_my_diffs_prtty!`:

```
def self.make_my_diffs_pretty!
  require "pp"

  define_method :mu_pp, &:pretty_inspect
end
```

So ignoring the tiny potential performance loss from `require 'pp'`, let's consider the impact of redefining the `mu_pp` method.

For example, let's now look at [the source code for the `diff` assertion method](https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/blob/d222b4e5ca5f893370e18bd3cd991370c6a7a255/lib/minitest/assertions.rb#L59-L85):

```
def diff exp, act
  expect = mu_pp_for_diff exp
  butwas = mu_pp_for_diff act
  result = nil

  need_to_diff =
    (expect.include?("\n")    ||
     butwas.include?("\n")    ||
     expect.size > 30         ||
     butwas.size > 30         ||
     expect == butwas)        &&
    Minitest::Assertions.diff

  return "Expected: #{mu_pp exp}\n  Actual: #{mu_pp act}" unless
    need_to_diff

  Tempfile.open("expect") do |a|
    a.puts expect
    a.flush

    Tempfile.open("butwas") do |b|
      b.puts butwas
      b.flush

      result = `#{Minitest::Assertions.diff} #{a.path} #{b.path}`
      result.sub!(/^\-\-\- .+/, "--- expected")
      result.sub!(/^\+\+\+ .+/, "+++ actual")

    # ...
end

def mu_pp_for_diff obj
  mu_pp(obj).gsub(/\\n/, "\n").gsub(/:0x[a-fA-F0-9]{4,}/m, ":0xXXXXXX")
end
```

The `mu_pp` method is called *before* outputting the result of a failed test. It's also used as part of the actual check.

In addition, the line: `return "Expected: #{mu_pp exp}\n  Actual: #{mu_pp act}" unless need_to_diff` is acting as a *performance enhancement*: By taking a short-cut the diff will "obviously" fail. However, by making use of the `make_my_diffs_pretty!` method, note that `expect.size` and `actual.size` will now be significantly larger - therefore the "full check" will be conducted more often.